# Are aluminum electrolytic capacitors suitable for encapsulation/potting?

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor, potting

Because aluminum electrolytic capacitors generally incorporate a venting mechanism for over-temperature/over-pressure events, are they suitable for complete encapsulation in potting compound?

Specifically, I am evaluating the compatibility between a surface mount 10V [Nichicon UWT-series cap](https://products.nichicon.co.jp/en/pdf/XJA043/e-uwt.pdf) and a polyurethane-based potting compound used in automotive applications.

Is it OK to pot this type of capacitor? If encapsulation is not recommended, what alternate types should I consider for 100µF bulk capacitor purposes?

Comment: Re alternatives: you didn't mention voltage rating.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, it's a 10V-rated cap. The device supply voltage is max 3.6V.

Comment: Well there are doubts about potting e-caps but you can parallel up ceramic capacitors and pot them no problem.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm considering aluminum polymer (Nichicon PCG series), but I'm unsure if they have similar venting/safety issues. I sought to ask more experienced engineers while I continue to research. :)

Comment: I like Andy's idea here. Two 47µF X7R/Y5V ceramics in parallel will outperform many 100µF electrolytics and never leak.

Comment: If you use ceramic, and the capacitance matters, check the voltage coefficient and use a relatively high voltage/bigger capacitor if necessary.  For example, GRM31CE70J476ME15L "47uF"/6.3V 1206 are typically 25uF with 3.3V bias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some cautions [from TDK](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/530704/6ad5ed9e1ff4f727c328cb92da2adf2b/pdf-generaltechnicalinformation.pdf):

[image]

Seems like partially potting a capacitor with a top vent (letting the top part poke out) may be acceptable.

Be careful about the temperatures, PU potting compounds are exothermic when curing and can get very hot.

Comment: I've seen it done before, where everything is potted, but the top 0.5 - 1mm of elec. caps are exposed.

Comment: @Aaron Just to clarify, leaving some of the cap exposed isn't an option in my application because of moisture and potential corrosion of the cap surface.